# How to check if the ArrayList is null OR not using c:if in JSTL?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to check if the ArrayList is null OR not using JSTL **c:if** and it is not working. Please help me out in this.

My code is here

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%
java.util.ArrayList<Student> studentList = MyClass.getStudentList();
%>
<c:if test="${studentList != null}">
     <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
          <c:out value="${student.name}" />
     </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

I also tried

```
<%
java.util.ArrayList<Student> studentList = MyClass.getStudentList();
%>
<c:if test="${not empty studentList}">
     <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
          <c:out value="${student.name}" /><br/>
     </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

as well as

```
<%
java.util.ArrayList<Student> studentList = MyClass.getStudentList();
request.setAttribute("studentList", studentList);
%>
<c:if test="${not empty studentList}">
     <c:forEach var="student" items="${studentList}">
          <c:out value="${student.name}" /><br/>
     </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Simple **c:if** expressions like  are working.

What am I doing wrong in this code? Any clues?

Comment: Also tried request attribute as well as *varStatus="loop"* attribute.

Comment: I am using JRE 6 and Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. That was the issue with JAR files. Now I downloaded JARS from [Java.Net](http://jstl.java.net/download.html) site and it is working.

Answer (score 2):

The JSP EL doesn't manipulate local variables of the JSP. It manipulates objects stored in one of the four scopes:

- pageScope
- requestScope
- sessionScope
- applicationScope

For this code to work, you would have to do:

```
<%
java.util.ArrayList<Student> studentList = MyClass.getStudentList();
pageContext.setAttribute("studentList", studentList);
%>
```

But the JSP EL and JSP taglibs have been introduced to avoid using Java code in the JSPs. scriptlets should not be used. Use a servlet for your Java code, and dispatch to the JSP for the rendering code. Or use an MVC framework like Stripes or Spring MVC.

Comment: Tried that too. Sorry for not posting that. Posting that.

Comment: You didn't try correctly then. Add another <c:if> for the inverse condition: your list is probably empty.

Comment: No. When I print using expression like out.print(studentList.get(0).getName()) then it is printing.

Comment: Add `${studentList}` to your page to see what it displays. And check your page source in the browser.

Comment: The list can't be both empty and not empty. Put an `<c:if>` for both conditions. What does it print when you add `${studentList}`? What does it print when you add `${studentList == null}`? What does it print when you add `${empty studentList}`?

Comment: I tried that in all four conditions. empty, not empty, == null and != null. c:if is not going inside.

Comment: You don't answer my questions. Put all these, out of your c:if tag, in the JSP, and tell me what it prints: `studentList = ${studentList}<br/>studentList is null: ${studentList == null}<br/> studentList is empty: ${empty studentList}<br/>`. And check what is generated in your page source.

Comment: +1 All four were coming blank. Thank I got doubt on the JARs I'm using. Now, I got a solution and that was the issue with JAR files. Posted it also. Thanks for support also directing me to use those four scopes.